# Do any non-Linux OS's run systemd?

Tags: linux, systemd

I know that the usage of `systemd` is dominated by various Linux distros.  Are there, in fact, any non-Linux operating systems that can run systemd?  Or any plans to introduce in on any non-Linux-OS's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the systemd Wikipedia page, there are no non-Linux operating systems that run `systemd`, although the `systemdbsd` project worked on porting some of the daemons to FreeBSD. Nor are plans for ports to other operating systems mentioned.

One of the creators of systemd explained at http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd.html
the systemd design is based on using Linux specific features to track the communication between services and the use of filesystems by services in order to greatly optimize start up. The blog post lists several of these features and explains that since systemd was designed around them, systemd is not expected to be portable to any other OS.